# iPhone iOS 6 UITabBarController Portrait Only, How to have Modal View Controller support Landscape Orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, uitabbarcontroller, landscape

What I'm trying to do is the simplest concept.  But, I'm just not getting any desired results.

My app is a standard Tab Bar app, all of the view controllers in each of the tabs support Portrait orientation only, which is exactly what I want.

However, in one section of the app, I display a modal view controller, which obviously covers the tab bar controller.  It is a text input screen, and I would very much like this view to be able to support Landscape orientation as well as portrait.  Then, once the user cancels out of that modal view controller, the tab bar controller would be displayed again, everything in portrait.

I have tried so many things, and nothing works.  If I tell the app to support both orientations, then the rotations occur correctly on the modal, but also on the rest of the app, which I do not want.

I have tried implementing all the new shouldAutorotate and supportInterfaceOrientations methods, and nothing ever seems to work.

The closest attempt I had to almost working, was I created a UITabBarController category in my app delegate, to fowarded the shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations.  This seemed to work initially, but for some reason, whenever cancelling out of my modal vc, my tab bar portion of the app was always shifted up by 20 pixels up behind the status bar?? I have no idea what that's all about.

I created a test app, in which there is no UITabBarController, and I was able to code my desired behavior with no problem, and it works perfectly.  So, clearly something with regard to Tab Bar Controller is making this a difficult issue.

Please let me know what the trick is in solving this simple concept.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by creating a couple of categories for UITabBarController and UINavigationController.  Here is the code I used:

```
@implementation UITabBarController (rotations)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

@end

@implementation UINavigationController (navrotations)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

@end
```

Then, of course each view controller I display would simple need to respond to the shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations methods.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently in ios6 and above, the way rotation works is different. So what you have to do is the following

1. In your .plist support all 4 orientations.
2. Subclass the UITabBarController (for e.g: CustomTabBarController)
3. In the CustomTabBarController put the following lines of code

   ```
   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
   }


   - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
   }
   ```
4. In your app delegate or where ever you are initializing UITabBarController, replace those instances with CustomTabBarController instances.
5. In your modal controller put the lines

   ```
   - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
   }

   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
       return NO;

   }
   ```

And it should all work.

Apparently the trick, I found is that, UITabBarController will not listen to your instructions. It will support all the orientations you mention in the .plist.

There fore you have to subclass it.

I tried doing all of the above and it works fine. Do let me know and I can send you the code if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input, however I was able to come up with a solution using categories instead, which I posted as answer.  I just can't 'accept' my answer for 2 days, due to SO rules.

Comment: This works perfect! One thing to note. If you are using a storyboard, you have to change the Custom Class on the Tab Bar Controller to the custom class you created.